# ACM certificate validation for wildcards failing to complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Given a configured hosted zone in an AWS account I´ve got the following configuration:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name         = var.hosted_zone_name
  private_zone = false
}

locals {
  domain_name = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name
  wildcard_domain = "*.${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name}"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "production_certificate" {
  domain_name       = local.domain_name
  validation_method = "DNS"

  subject_alternative_names = [
   local.wildcard_domain
  ]

  tags = {
    CoreResource = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "prod_cert_validation" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_acm_certificate.production_certificate
  ]
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.production_certificate.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name   = dvo.resource_record_name
      record = dvo.resource_record_value
      type   = dvo.resource_record_type
    }
  }

  allow_overwrite = true
  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = local.zone_id
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "validation" {
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.production_certificate.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = aws_acm_certificate.production_certificate.domain_validation_options[*].resource_record_name
  depends_on = [
    aws_route53_record.prod_cert_validation
  ]
}
```

This is trying to create a certificate that can be reused for different subdomains. I´ve executed this several times waiting enough (more than a couple hours) and even destroyed the terraform stack starting from scratch.

The hosted zone is never been deleted.

I'm wondering if I should change any minor thing in this tf config given that I need a wildcard and that I'm setting it as SAN.

I´ve did some research through the AWS CLI and I could see:

**Certificate keeps appearing in pending validation state with a pair of validation options:**

```
"SubjectAlternativeNames": [
  "prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>",
  "*.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>"
],
"DomainValidationOptions": [
    {
        "DomainName": "prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>",
        "ValidationDomain": "prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>",
        "ValidationStatus": "PENDING_VALIDATION",
        "ResourceRecord": {
            "Name": "_cb013815ac8693403158961c54b66d2f.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
            "Type": "CNAME",
            "Value": "_011037ffa048159e38a797e332dc2824.yssrbzrnkq.acm-validations.aws."
        },
        "ValidationMethod": "DNS"
    },
    {
        "DomainName": "*.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>",
        "ValidationDomain": "*.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>",
        "ValidationStatus": "PENDING_VALIDATION",
        "ResourceRecord": {
            "Name": "_cb013815ac8693403158961c54b66d2f.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
            "Type": "CNAME",
            "Value": "_011037ffa048159e38a797e332dc2824.yssrbzrnkq.acm-validations.aws."
        },
        "ValidationMethod": "DNS"
    }
]
```

**Also, one of the validation records seems to get created (after several minutes)**

```
{
  "ResourceRecordSets": [
      {
        "Name": "prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
        "Type": "NS",
        "TTL": 172800,
        "ResourceRecords": [
            {
              "Value": "ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.org."
            },
            {
              "Value": "ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.net."
            },
            {
              "Value": "ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.co.uk."
            },
            {
              "Value": "ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.com."
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
        "Type": "SOA",
        "TTL": 900,
        "ResourceRecords": [
            {
              "Value": "ns-xxx.awsdns-xx.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400"
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "_cb013815ac8693403158961c54b66d2f.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
        "Type": "CNAME",
        "TTL": 60,
        "ResourceRecords": [
            {
              "Value": "_011037ffa048159e38a797e332dc2824.yssrbzrnkq.acm-validations.aws."
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "trial-us-prod-us-east-1.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "Z35SXDOTRQ7X7K",
          "DNSName": "trial-us-prod-us-east-1-414890632.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.",
          "EvaluateTargetHealth": true
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "trial-us-prod-us-west-2.prod.content-marketing.<some-private-domains-here>.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "Z1H1FL5HABSF5",
          "DNSName": "trial-us-prod-us-west-2-1566505944.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.",
          "EvaluateTargetHealth": true
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you get your custom domain in R53, or is it externally purchased?

Comment: Are you able to resolve your custom domain name? This is likely not a Terraform issue, but and problem with AWS not being able to validate you are the owner of the domain because they cannot resolve the validation CNAME records you have.

If this is a subdomain, but sure you are delegating the nameservers correctly (and they match the parent domain).

Comment: @Marcin and @Taylor the domain is R53 managed, I removed the SAN domains and just made it `"*.hosted_zone_domain"` and it went through pretty quickly, close to immediately

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while trying to validate a wildcard and an apex domain using Cloudflare. AWS ACM creates the requests the same required records for both so by the time the second record was trying to create the record there was an existing record with the same name and values. My fix was to exclude the wildcard record from `aws_acm_certificate_validation` by excluding it:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "certificate_validation" {
  for_each = {
    for i in aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options : i.domain_name => {
      name    = i.resource_record_name
      record  = i.resource_record_value
      type    = i.resource_record_type
    }
   # Skips the domain if it doesn't contain a wildcard
    if length(regexall("\\*\\..+", i.domain_name)) > 0
  }

  zone_id = cloudflare_zone.zone.id
  name    = each.value.name
  value   = each.value.record
  type    = each.value.type
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = false
}
```

More context on this issue here:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16913